# show success message after validation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, bootstrapvalidator

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Send</button>
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message"></div>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
    //validation for inputs
    }).on('valid.bs.validator', function(){
      $('button').click(function(){
        $('#success_message').show();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I'm trying to show the success message when I click submit button after all the validation but nothing happens when I hit submit button.

Comment: Please share the plugin details as well.